# How do I correct my code so that the 'onclick' toggler component applies only to the icon?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a collapsible component made with javascript. I want it to work so that when you click the icon the menu drops down/collapses. The way that it is currently working is that if you click anywhere on the entire line this rule applies.

```js
const collapsibles = document.querySelectorAll(".collapsible");
collapsibles.forEach((item) =>
  item.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("collapsible--expanded");
  })
);
```

```css
.collapsible__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.collapsible__heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.collapsible__chevron {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.collapsible__content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.collapsible--expanded .collapsible__chevron {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.collapsible--expanded .collapsible__content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
}

.collapsible .icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible">
  <header class="collapsible__header">
    <h2 class="collapsible__heading">Item 1</h2>
    <svg class="icon icon--white collapsible__chevron">
      <use xlink:href="images/integratesprite.svg#chevron"></use>
    </svg>
  </header>
  <div class="collapsible__content">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, adipisci.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a span with the class of the SVG since the SVG is invisible.

The code should work on the svg if you remove the span

```js
document.querySelector(".collapsible__chevron").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  this.closest(".collapsible").classList.toggle("collapsible--expanded");
})
```

```css
.collapsible__header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.collapsible__heading {
  margin-top: 0;
}

.collapsible__chevron {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

.collapsible__content {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.collapsible--expanded .collapsible__chevron {
  transform: rotate(0);
}

.collapsible--expanded .collapsible__content {
  max-height: 100vh;
  opacity: 1;
}

.collapsible .icon {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="collapsible">
  <header class="collapsible__header">
    <h2 class="collapsible__heading">Item 1</h2><span class="icon icon--white collapsible__chevron">▼</span>
  </header>
  <div class="collapsible__content">
    Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, adipisci.
  </div>
</div>
```